# Handlerbarjs : How to add extra content to {{#each}} content

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

for example i have code like below which with generate some text

```
{{#each test1}}
<p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

and let's consider if render something like

Tom,peter,ken

But i'd like to add some extra symbol for them like

[Tom],[peter],[ken]

can i assign the backet to those result with handlebarjs?

i suppose it would be like ?

```
 {{#each test1}}
    <p>[ {{name}} ]</p>
    {{/each}}
```

this only returns

[Tom,peter,ken]

not

[Tom],[peter],[ken]

Answer (score 0):

Try this to append comma:

```
{{#each test1}}
<p>[{{name}}]{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it? In your updated, why has commas in [Tom,peter,ken]. I suspect that `test1` only has 1 element, which `name` is `Tom,peter,ken`

Answer (score 0):

Within a handlebar template, things inside double curly braces have a special meaning, as they are the placehoders where values are put. Everything else is treated the same way as they would be in regular HTML. So, to print [ ], you simply use their respective codes

```
{{#each test1}}
    <p> &#91; {{name}} &#93; </p>
{{/each}}
```